# c++ - adding new values to an array of ints

Tags: c++, arrays

In my code below I have an array of objects - tArray.
I am trying to find the 'buyer names' that have the top five total 'num shares',
the calctotal, and calcstring arrays work in tandem to store the buyer and his total value.

However, I have stepped through the code when running and my code is essentially replacing the values that are smaller that the current 'numshares' in the loop. This means even if a buyer that was just replaced comes up again his total starts new and is not added, which is want I want.

How would I change this code so when a larger value is found that smaller value is pushed further down into the array and not replaced?

Thanks - I am bound to this 'format' of solving the problem (assignment) so achieving the functionality is the goal so I can progress.

So, essentially the second if statement is were the issue lies:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<nTransactions; i++)
{
    //compares with arrays
    for(int j =0; j<sSize; j++)
    {
        if(tArray[i].buyerName == calcString[j])
        {
        calcTotal[j] += tArray[i].numShares;
        break;
        }
        else{
                //checks if shares is great then current total then replaces
                if(tArray[i].numShares > calcTotal[j])
                {
                    calcTotal[j] = tArray[i].numShares;
                    calcString[j] = tArray[i].buyerName;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
return calcString;
}
```

Comment: "How would I change this code so when a larger value is found that smaller value is pushed further down into the array and not replaced?" This sounds like you are sorting the array. Is that really what you want to do or are you trying to simply search the array based on some criteria?

Comment: Yeah essentially as a new larger value is found on say the third iteration of the second loop I need instead of just over writing the value that is currently there I would need it inserted. hopefully this helps

Comment: If you are doing a search, I suggest that you simply keep track of the "largest found so far" as a separate variable, possibly just an index into the arrray.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to find the largest totals only looking at 1 transaction at a time. You need to aggregate the totals for all the buyers first. Then it is a simple matter to  find the 5 highest totals.

Comment: I need to program the problem so that it could possibly accommodate 1000 different buyers for example - so adding up all he totals for each one does not seem effecient, which is what we also get judged on. I am hitting a wall on this to be honest :/

Comment: @user2075995 I can't see how you can determine the 5 biggest without keeping a running tally of all of them. The trick here would be to keep the running tally on all of them while tracking the 5 largest at the same time in separate structure in a single iteration of the trancsactions.